# Warning: Undefined property: wpdb::$question_overview in C:\Wamp.NET\sites\proxyvragenmodule\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wpdb.php

Tags: php, wpdb

My question on stackoverflow was asked on the wrong part of my code

I have an error that ive been dealing with since forever.. Im making a question viewer in wordpress and it shows this error

Warning: Undefined property: wpdb::$question_overview

This is my code, i dont see whats wrong with it.

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->question_overview;
$wpdb->get_results(" SELECT DISTINCT, uniq_name FROM  question_overview WHERE status='email' AND answer=' NULL");
$wpdb->get_results ("SELECT DISTINCT, uniq_name FROM  question_overview WHERE status='open'");
// Select the uniq_id for the questions which you are selected for
 $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT DISTINCT, uniq_name FROM  question_overview WHERE 'email'='email' AND answer=' NULL");
// Loop through all questions where the user email is in       
$wpdb->get_results(" SELECT DISTINCT, uniq_name FROM  question_overview WHERE status='open' AND email='".$email."'");
// Loop through the answers corresponding to the selected questions from above
global $wpdb;
$result= $wpdb->question_overview;
```

Comment: Your posted code does not show `question_overview` being defined.

Comment: then how to define it

Comment: What's it supposed to be? The result of one of those queries?

Comment: Yes thats whats supposed to be